# What is Elasticsearch date histogram pre/post rounding?

Tags: elasticsearch

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#_pre_post_offset gives a brief description of pre/post offsets for Elasticsearch date histograms. But I don't understand what it means. What does Elasticsearch do with the pre and post offsets? What are "pre rounding" and "post rounding"?

Comment: That section is probably not meant to be read in isolation. Try first rading the documentation for the normal 'histogram' and then the 'time zone' section of the date histogram

Comment: I tried that but I'm still confused.